# Faulty Regex or strange behavior?

Tags: python, regex, parsing

Hello i post my question here because i don't understand my potential error. I am parsing ingredients'lists. Some of them have allegations in it such as '*no-ogm'. I succeed in extracting most of this allegations in a dictionary in order to extract directly from other ingredients lists allegation already referenced. Issue is that my regex works in all online regex tester but no in my jupyter notebook and i do not understand why. Here is an example:

```
string='''chickpeas* (31%), water, sesame oil* (11%), tofu* (soybeans*, water, gelling agent (nigari (magnesium chloride))), onions*, carrots*, yeast*, celery*, non-hydrogenated sunflower oil*, cashew nuts*, tomato paste*, vegetable bouillon* (sea salt, maize starch*, glucose syrup*, sunflower oil*, carrots*, onion*, parsnips*, turmeric*, ginger*, parsley*, nutmeg*, lovage*, bay leaves*, black pepper*), sea salt, ginger*, locust bean*, coriander*, turmeric*, cumin*, fenugreek*, nutmeg, black pepper*, cinnamon*, mustard seeds*, cardamom*, cayenne pepper* *from organic agriculture'''
```

and the regex:

```
pattern=re.findall('\*{1,3}\s{0,2}\bfrom organic agriculture\b\s{0,2}$',string)
```

In Regex101 and Pythex the subset of the string '*from organic agriculture' is clearly found. In my jupyter notebook pattern return 'None'... Why? i tried many regex flags to correct this behavior but... nothing worked.

This issue is particularly problematic at large scale because as i have a dictionary of allegations as mentioned above, i loop through each of my dictionary key to find corresponding patterns in multiple strings.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 3):

You should use so-called raw-string here i.e. in place of:

```
pattern=re.findall('\*{1,3}\s{0,2}\bfrom organic agriculture\b\s{0,2}$',string)
```

do

```
pattern=re.findall(r'\*{1,3}\s{0,2}\bfrom organic agriculture\b\s{0,2}$',string)
```

This is crucial if you use regex class characters, like `\s`.

Comment: effectively it is now workin but i do not understand why i need here the raw-string char. I need to have a deeper look to python regex documentation... i don't like to not understand. Thanks a lot for your quick answear!

Comment: @TristanSalord: if you like to understand read [re docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html) starting at `Regular expressions use the backslash`...

Answer (score 1):

Either double backslashes before `b` in your pattern: `'\*{1,3}\s{0,2}\\bfrom organic agriculture\\b\s{0,2}$'` (other such characters are newline, `\`. `'`, `"`, `a`, `f`, `n`, `r`, `t`, `v`, `x`, followed by a hexadecial character code), or prepend the pattern with `r`: `r'\*{1,3}\s{0,2}\bfrom organic agriculture\b\s{0,2}$'`, so that the backslashes are not treated as beginning of escape sequences (https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html).

Comment: what i understand from your answear is that re.search('\*',string) won't be problematic but if you want to capture '* %', fo example, you need sthg like re.search(r'\*\s\%') because you are dealin with a sequence of specific chars?

Comment: @Tristan Salord, Python gives a special meaning to some sequences starting with a backslash in string literals, including `\b`, which is the backspace character (see https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html).

Comment: Oh gosh! it was that????!!! Thanks a lot.... Damned!